# OpenGL: What are best practices for using FBO textures?

Tags: c++, opengl, textures, rendering, game-engine

For context, I was mulling over a design where static UI elements can be rendered to a texture and drawn, instead of drawing each separate UI element every frame. And then I thought, "Wait, couldn't you do this for everything?" Instead of drawing each tile in a tile map, couldn't you just draw it once on a big texture and use that?

Although this would seem like a good idea, I don't really know what the best practices are for this type of texture use.

Some possible questions/topics:

- Why is binding a texture so slow? Does glBindTexture() push the texture to a higher memory cache for access?
- In the case of the tile map example, does drawing large textures pose performance issues? Is it better to draw multiple smaller textures?

Comment: one of the downside is that you can't parallax when it's been rendered to a static background

Comment: The main issue of pre-rendering is memory usage; that texture will likely be huge. Using an array texture or texture atlas can reduce the number of texture binds needed for rendering tiles on-demand.

Comment: "Is it better to draw multiple smaller textures". 
You will want to make as few state changes as possible as in don't change texture for each render call. This will for sure be bad for performance. To avoid this you should put your whole UI in an atlas so that you can draw all of the elements with one render call. To be able to do that you need to batch your UI mesh.

Comment: Size of the texture isn't an issue.  Lots (thousands) of binds might be, yes.  You can use texture arrays for this though.

Comment: Lots of things make binding textures slow, but something to consider with respect to textures and framebuffer objects is that they have a _lot_ more states than most OpenGL object types. Driver overhead for things like state validation play a much larger part of the performance and have nothing to do with any sort of hardware limitation. You might consider reading the recent presentation on "Approaching Zero Driver Overehead"; the idea is to batch as much work possible with as few API calls as possible and changing textures has traditionally been the biggest obstacle to that.